# How to import excel file in react-native to upload in api

Tags: reactjs, excel, react-native, react-native-community

I want to pick excel file from my phone storage and upload in api

I try to pick excel file from `react-native-document-picker`

but in the response I got URI in this format `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/8633`

with this I'm not able to upload excel file in api

Answer (score 0):

Did you try replacing `content//` with `file//` and uploading? Also, make sure you upload form data by appending file uri, name and type.

To replace you can use:

```
// Convert URI to file path
    const filePath = res.uri.replace('content://', 'file://');
```

If it doesn't work please share your code snippet. Thanks :)